# Can mxGraph use UUID to replace the id generated default with integer type?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

The id of mxCell is used integer type with increment 1 each time by default, but we want to replace it to UUID type. What's the better way to overwrite the default function? Thanks

```
mxGraphModel.prototype.createId = function(cell)
{
    var id = this.nextId;
    this.nextId++;

    return this.prefix + id + this.postfix;
};
```

I have changed the above method, but I am not sure whether it will influence other modules in mxGraph.

```
mxGraphModel.prototype.createId = function(cell)
{
    var id = myUtils.getUUID()     //a method to return an UUID

    return this.prefix + id + this.postfix;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine, as long as the generated numbers are unique. What the actual values are doesn't matter.

Overriding the prototype is also fine if your intent is to do it for all `mxGraphModel` instances.